# What limits the number of USB devices with identical VIDs?

Tags: windows-10, usb, drivers

### Context:

I have five Atmel microprocessor development boards and one Atmel ICE programmer.  All of the devices connect to Windows via USB and enumerate as USB Composite Devices.

### Problem:

When I plug in any five of the above USB devices (in any order), there's no problem.  But when I plug in the *sixth* (whether it's a development board or the ICE programmer), it's not recognized and Device Manager reports

> This device cannot start.  (Code 10)  Insufficient system resources exist to complete the API.

### Some details:

After plugging in the sixth Atmel device (and getting the error), I can still plug in additional non-Atmel USB devices (e.g. a SEGGER J-Link) without an error.  So it's not like I'm out of USB resources.

I note that all the Atmel USB devices share the same VID (03EB), but have a few different PIDs (2111, 2141, 2169).

None of the devices are power hogs, and they are distributed across three tp-link USB 3.0 7-port hubs with 2.4A supplies, so I don't suspect lack of power is an issue.

### Environment:

- Windows 11 Pro, V 21H2, Buld 22000.176
- Intel NUC-10 (i5-8259U, 2.3GHz)
- 64-bit OS, x64-based processor
- 32GB RAM

### Questions:

Is this a known problem?
Is there a workaround?
Is there additional information I should collect to diagnose this problem?

Comment: Question: How much power do these devices draw? How much is available across all your USB ports?

Comment: @harrymc Updated the OP with power info.  I distributed the units across three USB powered hubs -- no change.

Comment: Is there any relevancy to ports that are USB 2.0 or 3.0?

Comment: @harrymc The tp-link port hubs support USB 3.0, but all of the connected devices are USB 2.0 (if I have the correct terminology...)

Comment: @fearless_fool, did you ever solve this problem? I have a similar problem, but it seems the limit gets set dynamically at boot somehow... Any number of USB devices plugged in at boot work fine (no errors), but adding any USB device gets Code 10/"Insufficient system resources", even devices which worked before on that PC. But if I unplug a device which was present at boot and then plug in a different device, the new device works fine (but re-adding the other fails with the same resource issue)... super strange

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

- Run `regedit` and navigate to
  `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control`
- Find the 32-digit subkey relating to your devices
- Delete the items `UpperFilters` and `LowerFilters` items
- Reboot at least twice.

For more information about a similar problem see the article
[Fix: Insufficient System Resources Exist to Complete the Api Xbox Controller](https://www.partitionwizard.com/clone-disk/insufficient-system-resources-exist-to-complete-the-api.html#solution-3.-delete-the-upperfilters-and-lowerfilters-values-using-registry-editor-2388).

Comment: I see no evidence that I'm having the same problems as described in that article.  Before I modify `regedit`, will you elaborate as to why you believe this is the appropriate fix?